# Mootools 1.1/1.2 border or border color in FX.Styles not able to change/set NaNpx error

Tags: mootools

This is driving me mad , I have a code that works perfect with FX. Morph in 1.2.x  all values also work in 1.1  but the border-color or border simply do not work and trow NaNpx error.

```
        var fx = new Fx.Styles(element,{ duration:500,wait:false });
            element.addEvents({
                'mouseenter': function() { fx.start({ 
                'background-color':'#ff8c00',
                'border-color':'1px solid #cccccc'
            });
```

I checked and getStyle('border') in moo 1.1  returns  1px solid #fffff
but border-color returns 4x #ffffff for each border I guess , so how should I declare this properly , each border , border-width , border-style , 
I have tried all the above and all of them trow error. Most cases NaNpx

Here is JSfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/b44Wp/8/

when you switch from 1.1.2  to 1.2.5  change  Styles to Morph , and now on that example even 1.2.5 is trowing the same error but it shows the black border.

As soosn as I use the border IE7 does not work at all , background color works fine . I am sorry but I have to support multiple browsers including our "best friend"

If you know better solution which would be simply transition another div class in and keep same visual effect please please advise. Thank you!!

Comment: no one? please please give it shoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put 'border-color' as property ;) http://jsfiddle.net/xDWZr/

```
var myelement = $$('.mydiv');

myelement .each(function(myelement ) {  
    var fx = new Fx.Styles(myelement ,{ duration:500,wait:false});
        myelement.addEvents({
            'mouseenter': function() { fx.start({ 
            'background-color':'#ff8c00',
            'border-color':'#000000'
        }); 
},
          'mouseleave': function() { fx.start({ 
             'background-color':'#ffffff',
            'border-color':'#CCCCCC'
         }); 
  }
   });
 });
```

but...u should also update to a newer mootools version (now it's 1.4.1)  ;)

Comment: tried that one also ,  as advised above and it produces same error , look in your console on the example you set. that error is casuing issue in IE7, solution to this was for moo 1.1  'border-color': ['F9F9F9', 'cccccc'] it needs ending and start

Comment: @stecb ,   as advised previously I must support all moo versions

Answer (score 0):

solution for  moo 1.1 'border-color': ['F9F9F9', 'cccccc']  all other moo versions can use border: '1px solid #cccccc'